# Etcd integration with SparkJava REST API framework for Java

Tags: spark-java, etcd

I am trying to use below etcd framework in SparkJava

https://github.com/AdoHe/etcd4j

Code looks like below:

```
get("/hello",(request, response) -> {

String value;           


try {
    EtcdClient client = new EtcdClient(URI.create("http://127.0.0.1:2379"));
    String key = "/message";
    value = client.get(key);
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

return value;});
```

However when i try to access the url as below
http://localhost:4567/hello

I get following error

```
HTTP ERROR: 500
Problem accessing /hello. Reason:
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
Powered by Jetty:// 9.3.6.v20151106
```

What am i missing here? etcd working when used as standalone project with main() function, however not working with SparkJava, Is there any etcd client which works with SparkJava?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it to work with the following Etcd client:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mousio</groupId>
        <artifactId>etcd4j</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Here's the code:

```
private static String etcdGet(Request request, Response response) {
    EtcdClient client = new EtcdClient(URI.create("http://<ip-address>:2379"));
    String key = "/message";

    try {
        EtcdResponsePromise<EtcdKeysResponse> value;
        value = client.get(key).send();
        return value.get().getNode().getValue();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```